# how to use Rxjava to update user interface from service even when app is closed

Tags: android, service, rx-java, event-bus

I have a service which send some messages to server, I want user to keep track with failed messages allowing him to resend them any time.

I used an eventbus util with rxjava to post updates to ui, it works nicely when app is open, but when app is closed ui doesn't receive eventbus events.
I tried to post events to a local list saved in shared preference, and read data from it when user opens app, but it seems that not a good solution.

Comment: Maybe you can show notification on status bar and upon user click sending will retry.

Comment: I searched for that solution a little, it is called forgroundServic(), which is a service with -as you described- notification with status bar, but I don't know if I'm going to do it .. because that will make me rewrite the whole service. @AleksanderMielczarek

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim You already use shared preference as a cache memory alternative use can you sqlite.But this is good way because as per your requirement while app closed where you have to update data updates? or you have to open app and update data?

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran so I discovered that the problem is service been killed if user closes or kills app, my problem now is how to keep service alive even app is killed, or just label message as failed with retry option.